# ReflectionClass cast to "normal" Class

Tags: php, reflection

I have a class TableData with two magic methods. One is the constructor and the other is the __call method.

I have realized the invoke with following code:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('TableData');
$class->newInstanceArgs($parArray);
```

It work great. But now I want to use my magic method. So I call `$class->getData()`, but it doesn't work. I get the error, that I called an undefined method.
I tried to use ReflectionMethod and invoke, but it doesn't work again.

Is there no way to cast the ReflectionClass Object to my TableData class?

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't call the method on the instance of `ReflectionClass`. You have to call the method on the **instance** of your (reflected) original class.

```
$class    = new ReflectionClass('TableData');
$instance = $class->newInstanceArgs($parArray);
$instance->getData();
```

Answer (score 2):

What about first getting the `ReflectionClass` :

```
class MyClass {
  public function __call($method, $args) {
    var_dump($method);
  }
}

$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');
```

And, then, instanciating the class :

```
$class = $reflectionClass->newInstanceArgs();
```

To call your method on that `$class` object :

```
$class->getData();
```

And you'll get the expected result :

```
string 'getData' (length=7)
```

i.e. you have to call your methods on what is returned by `newInstanceArgs`, and not on the `ReflectionClass` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you are using Reflection here at all. Maybe you better want to modify your constructor to accept an array?

Reasons not to use Reflection are slowness and unreadability:
This is much easier to use and understand:

```
$instace = new TableData($parArray);
```

Than this:

```
$class    = new ReflectionClass('TableData');
$instance = $class->newInstanceArgs($parArray);
```

So, if you want your constructor to handle both an array as argument and a list of arguments, you can use `func_get_args`:

```
class TableData {
    public function __constructor() {
        if (func_num_args() != 1 || !is_array($params = func_get_arg(0))) {
            $params = func_get_args();
        }

        // now the args are in $params either way
    }
}
```

Comment: I used because the number of arguments is not even the same.
I had from 5 arguments til 15 arguments so I found the solution with Reflection better.